# Why is "seiner" used here?

Tags: grammar-identification

Why is it *seiner* used in the following sentence?

> Das Schicksal des jüdischen Mädchens, das 1933 mit seiner Familie aus Frankfurt....

I do not understand why *seiner* is used instead of *ihrer*.

Comment: @Rompey It's not genitive.

Answer (score 5):

Which gender does *Mädchen* have in German? Which should be the possesive pronoun accordingly? 
(hover the mouse on the box if you cannot solve by yourself after that).

> Because *Mädchen* is neutral (*das Mädchen*), the possessive pronoun is *sein*. *Familie* is femenine, thus *seiner*, since *mit* needs dative.

Comment: What does the age of the girl have to do with this?

Comment: Somehow I thought that the age could give more weight to the semantics than to the syntaxis. Mh, would my argument work with *Mädel*?

Comment: I don’t think it would work with “Mädel” either. Also, this might be a regional (I’m in northern Germany) or outdated word, since I’ve never read or heard it used outside of old texts or very old movies. It is a common colloquialism to use “ihre” with “Mädchen”. If “Frau” were used instead, there would be no disambiguity.

Comment: @Philipp Did you refer to "Mädel" when saying regional/outdated? Then, it's certainly regional, because "Mädel/Mädels" is well known to me.

Comment: @Em1 Yes, I meant »Mädel«. Of course, I know the word, but I've never heard it in  Hamburg.

Comment: I've edited. Hence, as I see it now, it's also false to say "Das Mädel, mit der er ausgeht..." ?

Comment: @Em1 It could also be related to age.

Comment: @c.p. yes, it should be "Das Mädel, mit dem er ausgeht"

Comment: @Philipp This wasn't quite accurate of me. When I said "well known to me", I didn't mean that I know this word but that the word occurs frequently enough to not be outdated.

Comment: @c.p. Beautiful word, "whence". Certainly more outdated than "Mädel", though. Anyway, that's not the reason I deleted the word, but I think a "because" clause deserves a main clause. :D

Comment: @Em1 *Because* also can answer a *why* question (e.g. the OP). Also, I'm not sure how outdated *whence* is, to me it just sounds formal.

Answer (score 2):

As you seem to have understood, *seiner* refers to *das jüdische Mädchen*. Now she is undoubtably female, the pronoun however depends on the **grammatical gender** of the noun *Mädchen*, which is neuter (because it is originally a diminutive, but that is not important, you just have to know the grammatical gender of a word and cannot rely on it agreeing with a natural one). For the same reason, it is

> [..], **das** 1933 [...].

For the forms of the personal pronoun, you can consult [the table on Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/er#er_.28Deutsch.29).

In the same way, I can say (rather clumsily):

> Ich bin eine Person, **die** versucht, dir mit **ihrer** Antwort zu helfen.

It does not matter whether I am a man or a woman, *Person* is a female noun.

Comment: To clarify: the connection between grammatical and natural gender is exactly zero. Mark Twain joked about this in his famous essay “The Awful German Language”. People, animals and some plants have a natural gender, and some few items are treated as if they had one (e. g. ships), but most things don’t. And the nouns describing these “things” (girl etc.) are just words like any other. The confusion arises because we use the word “gender”, which is not very accurate. Cf.: Scholten, Daniel: Denksport Deutsch, 2016.

Comment: @Philipp, it is not zero. It is not a coincidence that *Lehrerin* is female. Also, the genders of *Vater*, *Mutter*, *Bruder*, *Schwester* are as expected.